# How to set Exact XML element name in DomDocument with PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a form which on POST creates an XML based on the values in the form. I am using DOM DOCUMENT to create XML. I am giving exact element names when creating xml but when it is created the element names are in lowercase which my API is not accepting. for eg.

I am giving this as an input `<LSP_Name>JaVAS</LSP_Name>` and when it is created it forms like this `<lsp_name>JaVAS</lsp_name>`

I tried `$xml->formatOutput=true;` but had no luck.

Any one who had faced this similar issue ?

DOCUMENT CREATION

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

        $xml->formatOutput=true;
        $root = $xml->createElement("NewDataSet");
        $xml->appendChild($root);

        $LSP_Code   = $xml->createElement("LSP_Code");
        $LSP_CodeText = $xml->createTextNode(LSP_CODE);
        $LSP_Code->appendChild($LSP_CodeText);

        $docket = $xml->createElement("Docket");
        $root->appendChild($docket);
        $docket->appendChild($LSP_Code);
```

TIA

Comment: Nope: https://eval.in/463136 - You are sure that it is not treated as HTML at some point?

Comment: Yes it is treating as html i believe because I am storing that xml in a string variable and then passing it to the API Call. Its a GET api call with query param.

Comment: The problem is not in the source you posted. You need to find the point where it breaks.